# Is there a way to make time lapses with ffmpeg?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, timelapse

How can you make a time-lapse with FFmpeg on ubuntu? And I don't mean converting a video into a time-lapse. I mean recording your laptop screen at a sped-up pace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) filter.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -video_size 1280x720 -f x11grab -i :0 -vf "setpts=0.5*PTS" output.mp4
```